# Validation of a textbox, so that the value differed from another textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I want to validate a `textbox`, so that the `Text` value of `firstNameTextBox` differed from `nicknameTextBox`. I'm using `InitialValue` property of `RequiredFieldValidator`, like this -

```
 fieldValidatorInitialValue.InitialValue = firstNameTextBox.Text;
```

Here is the code:

```
        RequiredFieldValidator fieldValidatorInitialValue = new RequiredFieldValidator();
        TextBox firstNameTextBox = new TextBox(); 
        TextBox nicknameTextBox = new TextBox();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button submitButton = new Button();
            submitButton.CausesValidation = true;
            submitButton.Click += submitButton_Click;
            nicknameTextBox.ID = "nickname";
            firstNameTextBox.ID = "firstname";
            fieldValidatorInitialValue.ControlToValidate = firstNameTextBox.ID;
        }

        protected void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fieldValidatorInitialValue.InitialValue = nicknameTextBox.Text;
        }
```

However, using this code the validation doesn't work correctly, only after the second click on button. I also tried to put all of the `RequiredFieldValidator` code to `submitButton_Click` event handler, however it doesn't work at all in this case, could someone please help me with it?

Comment: in pageload put the condition if(!ispostback){}

Comment: Is this not a percect case of compare validator? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db330ayw(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.you should use CompareValidator  instead of RequiredFieldValidator, with Operator="NotEqual"

```
 <asp:CompareValidator runat="server"
                  ControlToValidate="tbFName"
                  ControlToCompare="tbLName"
                  Type="String"
                  Operator="NotEqual"
                  ErrorMessage="First and last name cannot be the same" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if(!IsPostBack)
       {
         Button submitButton = new Button();
         submitButton.CausesValidation = true;
         submitButton.Click += submitButton_Click;
         nicknameTextBox.ID = "nickname";
         firstNameTextBox.ID = "firstname";
         fieldValidatorInitialValue.ControlToValidate = firstNameTextBox.ID;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I think the way you are trying to compare "First name" and "Nick
>   Name" is unnecessarily complex.
>           Instead of that you can simply use CompareValidator and achieve the same task on single button click. Here , Add this on your
>   designer page:

```
 <asp:CompareValidator ID="comNames" runat="server"
     ControlToValidate="firstNameTextBox"
     ControlToCompare="nicknameTextBox"
     ErrorMessage="Error: Name cant be same"
     SetFocusOnError="True" Text="*"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

> In case you want to add Validator dynamically, Add CompareValidator
>        instead of RequiredFieldValidator and add following properties:

```
   ControlToValidate="firstNameTextBox"
ControlToCompare="nicknameTextBox"
ErrorMessage="Error: Name cant be same"
SetFocusOnError="True"
Text="*"
```

> Note: if you are using ValidationGroup for button,use same name of
>   ValidationGroup  for Validator also.